# How to append content in WordPress Text Editor with wp_update_post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a chat with WordPress. I'm looking for a way to append part of content in the end of an existing content in **WordPress Editor**. I suppose I need to use **wp_update_post** and in the **'post_content'** somehow I need to append the new content, not replacing it. Do you know some way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us the code you have, and the expected output?

Comment: I don't have code for this part yet. I'm wondering how to do it. I suppose I need to use **wp_update_post** and in the **'post_content'** somehow I need to append the new content, not replacing it

Answer (score -1):

you can use Jquery for this.

```
$("your tag ").append("<b>Appended in parent</b>");
$("your tag ").after("<b>Appended after parent</b>");
$("your tag ").before("<b>Appended before parent</b>");
$("your tag ").prepend("<b>Appended before parent</b>");
```